# Best way to filter int columns in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Imagine I have a table like this:

```
id  | value
----|------
1   | 1200
2   | 3450
3   | 1230
4   | 1245
5   | 4512
```

Both `id` and `value` are **Integer**, now I want to filter all rows that their `value` starts with `12`, in this case I want these ids: `1,3,4`.
I figure some different ways to do this:

1. Cast `value` field to `String` and then use `LIKE` or `regex` to filter
2. Use `div` to divide those values by 100 and then compare
3. Use `Shif-Right`  to shift those values by 2 then compare

In the first case I'm not really sure about the performance because working with strings get the most time. 
In the third case I don't know how to do it or is it even possible to do something like that?

Generally I want to know whats the best practice to do it and how? is there a better way that I couldn't find?

In addition, I'm using Postgres and working with SQLalchemy ORM,
so either a SQL query or SQLalchemy query will be accepted.

Comment: `where value >= 1200 and value < 1300`?

Comment: What about 12? or 12000? Will you be having values other than 1000 <= value <= 9999?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the `12` value is dynamic, it may have different length or value.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I exactly want to do what `LIKE` do. but in Integer Column.

Comment: @IljaEverilä also you can consider that all of value's length are same.

Comment: You should clarify the range of possible values. Is 127346582346 to be treated the same?

Comment: @s.m. yes it should be treated same. but note that all values have same length, so if there is `123456799` in values, we can be sure that all other values have same `9` length.

Comment: If there are a fixed number of digits and you know that number, you could take what ever "prefix" you're looking for, add 1 for upper limit, multiply with a suitable power of ten, and use the solution by @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I don't know the length, i just know all of them have same length.

Comment: In that case I'd say cast to text and go with that.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate length of them ?@IljaEverilä

Comment: This'd seem relevant to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959885/2681632